# Headless Chrome PDF print with session

Tags: java, pdf-generation, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to integrate the Headless Chrome tool for generating PDF reports in my project. I managed to have the PDF generated however, since the page needs a user session to show the html report. When I use the headless chrome cmd command to print pdf it is showing the login page of the app. Is there a way that we could pass a session or a cookie to the cmd line for it to generate the report properly.

Thanks

Comment: you need to make two requests; first to login and save session info (cookies); second to access the protected page inside the user session. second is the one you print to pdf.

Comment: @J.Win. could you possibly illustrate that point by making an answer to the OP's question?

Comment: It really depends on the website. I find less and less these days allow you to login with a cookie, my scrapers all use selenium now. But if you have an example you are trying, I can help go through it

Answer (score 0):

What you can do instead is pass a url to headless chrome that is a secret url that renders the page as it should, but without requiring authentication.

Typically, what I do render the HTML internally, and then upload that raw HTML to a .html file on a server like Amazon S3. And then I pass the Amazon S3 url to headless chrome.